# How does a SPA extract access token in OAuth2 implicit flow

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth-2.0

I have an angular based SPA and want to utilize OAuth2 Implicit flow [OAuth2 implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2)

With authorization server worked out, if I have an active session with it and I send put this URL in browser address bar

```
https://server.example.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=s6BhdRkqt3&state=xyz&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb HTTP/1.1
```

I get redirected correctly with access_token to

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
 Location: http://client.example.com/cb#access_token=2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAAs&state=xyz&token_type=example&expires_in=3600
```

The specification states that `client.example.com/cb` should return a web page (typically an HTML document with an embedded script) capable of accessing the full redirection URI including the fragment retained by the user-agent, and extract the access token. I have implemented a page with script fetches access_token from `window.location.hash` and it works.

Now since SPA is already loaded and I also need to do this for token renewals as well, I want to do this with an ajax request instead. However with ajax, the redirect is automatically followed and I only get the HTML page but access_token is lost. I can see the access_token in Location header of response but dont know how to access it.

[Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication) and [Okta](https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/implicit) seem to support silent authentication using implicit flow, how do they do it ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access_token could only be accessed via `location.hash` and ajax request wont update that, so there was no way this could be achieved via an ajax request.

Looked at how other libraries were doing it and found this: 
https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client#silent-renew

The trick was to create a hidden `iframe` and whenever a token is required, update the `src` attribute to constructed URL. Token will be available within the iframe, just pass it to `window.parent`.

To achieve this first attach an event listener to `window`

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveToken, false);

function receiveToken(event) {
  // event.data will contain hash value
  console.log ('token received ' + event.data) ;
}
```

and call this function whenever to need a new token

```
function fetchToken() {
    document.getElementById('iframe').src='https://server.example.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=s6BhdRkqt3&state=xyz&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb'
}
```

while `http://client.example.com/cb` should return something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.postMessage(location.hash, "http://client.example.com");
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

the second argument to `postMessage` here is `targetOrigin`, it should match which hostname where SPA is hosted. If you don't want this security restriction it can be set to `'*'`